# Expo React Native control audio while app in background

Tags: ios, reactjs, expo, native, audio-player

currently, I am using Expo (React Native) to create a music player. One feature of the music player is to play music in the background. This is possible by handing `true` to the property `staysActiveInBackground` of the function `setAudioModeAsync` as written in https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/. Additionally, I want to be able to stop the music when the application is in background. However, I don't find any description on how to access the music player controls when using Expo. I found some sources online from 2017 stating this is not possible. Is this feature supported meanwhile? An if it's not supported, does anyone how to use the music player controls in Expo except a default implementation?

Thanks in advance for the answers